# Do I have to put my application manually into multithreaded-mode if I want to use threads?

Tags: iphone, multithreading

i.e., I am creating a new thread like this:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(doSomething) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

will this automatically make my app multithreaded or must I do some extra work somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's automatic.  In the docs for that method:

> If this thread is the first thread
>   detached in the application, this
>   method posts the
>   NSWillBecomeMultiThreadedNotification
>   with object nil to the default
>   notification center.

GUI Cocoa apps are pretty much always multithreaded these days.

Answer (score 1):

This will make your app multithreaded, but you need to be really careful. If you don't manage your threads correctly, you're going to run into a lot of trouble further down the road.

You should look into `NSOperationQueue` and `NSOperation` and see how they work.

Together you can build a multithreaded app, that abstracts the concurrency into queues and separate operations that run on those queues.

Also as an aside, any methods that you do spawn onto a new thread will need to be wrapped inside an autorelease pool. New threads don't have their own autorelease pool by default, so you need to set up your own.